# Not finding NSUserDefaults plist in simulator folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, plist

I know that there are other same questions as mine. But I think that I have tried everything and I still can't be able to find the NSUserDefaults plist file in my simulator folder. I made sure that I got the right ID for the simulator and I wasn't able to find the NSUserDefaults plist as I want to check exactly what values are being saved. Does anyone know what is the exact name of the file that I should be searching for?

For info, I am searching in the following path:
/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<device_id>/data/Library/Preferences

Does anyone know if I am doing it wrong? How can I find that file?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can print the location by asking at runtime.
Each time you compile and run simulator the folders may differ from before.

how to *write* NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults *userdef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userdef setObject:@"testString" forKey:@"testkey"];
[userdef synchronize]; //dont forget synchoniszing after setting new objects
```

how to *read* NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *result = [defs objectForKey:@"testkey"];
NSLog(@"read out userdefs = %@",result);
```

If you did not set any NSUserDefaults yet, there is no file.

Otherwise where is your `<BundleIdentifier>.<appName>.plist` ?

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryFolder = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appID = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
NSString *userdefFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Preferences/%@.plist", libraryFolder, appID];
NSLog(@"NSUserDefaults File located at: %@", userdefFile);
```